# What's the difference between this.$ and this.$$ in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I've read the documentation over and over and have googled with no luck. The [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom) start explaining this.$ with an example but then they don't give an example for what this.$$ does

As far as I understand it, this.$ will find something in my template with the ID I want. For example  - I can use this.$.test.textContent="hey there"

But for this.$$ it just says "dynamically-created nodes" - maybe someone can explain with an example what the difference between static and dynamic created nodes is, and how to use this.$$ - Thank you in advance!

Comment: The page you linked to states: For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element's local DOM, the $$ method provides a shorthand for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()`:

`this.$$(selector)`

Comment: Yes that's the sentence I was referring to in the question - I just don't know what olymer.dom(this.root).querySelector() does, so I don't know what this.$$(selector) does. And there's no example or explanation.

Comment: That's because it is assumed that people know what JavaScript's
`document.querySelector()` does: it selects the first element matching the selector, where `selector` is a String formatted like the one for a CSS rule. `this.$$("ul li")` will grab the first `<li>` in the first `<ul>`.

Comment: very helpful question, thank you

Answer (score 9):

`Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector` utilizes the shady DOM API.

Polymer with shady DOM (default in 1.0) doesn't fully polyfill shadow DOM.

To ensure all Polymer features, not natively supported by the browser, are taken into account correctly (like `<content>` projection) when using `querySelector()`) you need to use the `Polymer.dom(...)` wrapper.

- `this.$` is a getter that returns a static map from element id to the element reference. Elements created by `dom-repeat` or hidden by `dom-if` or otherwise created dynamically are not included.
- `this.$$()` is a shorthand function for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()` and therefor takes dynamically created elements into account, because it actually queries the DOM when executed.

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds like this.$$() will find everything, and this.$. will only find things I actually create in the outermost <template> tag of my element. Is that accurate?

Comment: Also, can you explain how I could find an attribute or property on a custom element from the javascript console on the main index page? For example <html><body><my-outer-element><my-inner-element my-id="hello" my-attribute="somedata">
I've been messing around with this.$.my-id (error), this.$$("#my-id") (empty [ ]) - for some reason document.getElementById("my-id") works... I'm really confused!

Comment: I think in the case of this.$$ it has access only to dynamically generated DOM elements, so it returns an empty array on pre-defined DOM elements, that's why there is both of this.$ & this.$$