# Cannot get element by id in Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, getelementbyid, polymer-2.x

I have a problem with getting HTML element inside `dom-repeat` in a function.

At first I had this code and it worked OK.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-button on-click="downloadTable">[[localize('Download')]]</paper-button>
  </app-toolbar>
  <table id="table" noshadow>
  <!--Table content here-->
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
downloadTable() {
    this.tableToExcel(this.$.table, 'table.xls');
}
```

But then I went from a single table to multiple tables which are iterated with `dom-repeat`.

HTML:

```
<template id="tablesRoot" is="dom-repeat" items="[[tables]]" as="table">
    <div class="card">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-button on-click="downloadTable">[[localize('Download')]]</paper-button>
      </app-toolbar>
      <table id={{table.elId}} noshadow>
      <!--elId is a string: table0, table1, table2, ... Table content here-->
      </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
downloadTable() {
    this.tableToExcel(this.$.table0, 'table.xls');
    //Trying to get the first table. Also tried without success:
    //this.$.tablesRoot.table0
    //this.$.tablesRoot.$.table0
}
```

In the element inspector is seems, ids are added correctly both for `table` and `dom-repeat`. But still cannot access any `table`. How I need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you cannot address dynamically created elements like this. Instead you have to use:

```
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#table0')
```

Comment: you can also call ```this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#table0')```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call

```
this.$$('#table0')
```

which is a shorthand for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#table0')`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970342/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this-in-polymer).